# Why do some apps look ugly after upgrade to 18.10?

Tags: themes, gtk, pygtk

For example Inkscape, or Deluge:
[image: Deluge]

Yaru theme is really nice, but why doesn't it work in some apps?

Comment: What's different/wrong with it? Have any screenshots of the old/right look?

Answer (score 0):

There is this issue: https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/issues/654

I was using Yaru Dark. Normal Yary makes all apps look ok. So as a workaround, I switched to this.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for Inkscape, the ugly look problem is fixed with the latest edge version.

Uninstall inkscape and then get the latest edge version using Snap:

```
sudo snap install inkscape --edge
```

For more information see:

https://snapcraft.io/inkscape